# How do I pass a string to epp_dodger?

Tags: erlang

I'm writing something to process Erlang source code. Pretty much the first line of the program is:

```
{ok, Forms} = epp_dodger:parse_file(Filename)
```

However, I want to do some simple unit testing. So: how do I persuade `epp_dodger` to take its input from a string instead of a file?

Alternatively, it has `epp_dodger:parse_form/2,3`, which takes an `IODevice`, so how do I provide an `IODevice` over a string?

Comment: Theoretically you could do a `file:open/2` on the string by passing the string as the file and including the `ram` option, but the resulting `IODevice` doesn't work with `epp_dodger` because it breaks when it gets passed down into the `io` module. I believe this is a bug.

Comment: I've reported the mishandling of the `IODevice` resulting from using the `ram` option as a bug.

Comment: Not a bug. I confused two separate `IODevice`-like types, one from the `file` module and one from the `io` module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below (which is admittedly a bit hackish) starts a `gen_server` that takes a string as an argument, and then fulfills the [Erlang I/O Protocol](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/stdlib/io_protocol.html) enough to satisfy `epp_dodger:parse/2` to be able to read and parse the string from that process.

Here's an example of using it:

```
1> {ok,P} = iostr:start("-module(x).\n-export([f/0]).\nf() -> ok.\n").
2> epp_dodger:parse(P,1).
{ok,[{tree,attribute,
         {attr,1,[],none},
         {attribute,
             {tree,atom,{attr,1,[],none},module},
             [{tree,atom,{attr,1,[],none},x}]}},
     {tree,attribute,
         {attr,2,[],none},
         {attribute,
             {tree,atom,{attr,2,[],none},export},
             [{tree,list,
                  {attr,2,[],none},
                  {list,
                      [{tree,arity_qualifier,
                           {attr,2,[],none},
                           {arity_qualifier,
                               {tree,atom,{attr,...},f},
                               {tree,integer,{...},...}}}],
                      none}}]}},
     {tree,function,
         {attr,3,[],none},
         {func,
             {tree,atom,{attr,3,[],none},f},
             [{tree,clause,
                  {attr,3,[],none},
                  {clause,[],none,[{atom,3,ok}]}}]}}]}
```

The process dies once the string is exhausted.

Note that the code probably misses a few things — handling unicode properly, for example — but it should give you a good idea of how to make a more robust I/O server for this purpose if needed.

```
-module(iostr).
-behaviour(gen_server).

-export([start_link/1, start/1, stop/1]).

-export([init/1, handle_call/3, handle_cast/2, handle_info/2,
         terminate/2, code_change/3]).

-record(state, {
          data,
          line = 1,
          lines
         }).

start_link(Data) ->
    gen_server:start_link(?MODULE, [Data], []).

start(Data) ->
    gen_server:start(?MODULE, [Data], []).

stop(Pid) ->
    gen_server:cast(Pid, stop).

init([Data0]) ->
    Data = [Line++"\n" || Line <- string:tokens(Data0, "\n")],
    {ok, #state{data=Data,lines=length(Data)}}.

handle_call(_Request, _From, State) ->
    {reply, ok, State}.

handle_cast(stop, State) ->
    {stop, normal, State};
handle_cast(_Msg, State) ->
    {noreply, State}.

handle_info({io_request,From,ReplyAs,{get_until,_,_,_,_,_}},
            #state{data=[],lines=L}=State) ->
    From ! {io_reply, ReplyAs, {eof,L}},
    {stop, normal, State};
handle_info({io_request,From,ReplyAs,{get_until,_,_,M,F,Args}},
            #state{data=Data,line=L}=State) ->
    case handler(Data,L,[],M,F,Args) of
        eof ->
            Lines = State#state.lines,
            From ! {io_reply, ReplyAs, {eof,Lines}},
            {stop, normal, State#state{data=[]}};
        {ok,Result,Rest,NData,NL} ->
            From ! {io_reply, ReplyAs, Result},
            case Rest of
                [] ->
                    {noreply, State#state{data=NData,line=NL}};
                _ ->
                    {noreply, State#state{data=[Rest|NData],line=NL}}
            end
    end;
handle_info(_Info, State) ->
    {noreply, State}.

terminate(_Reason, _State) ->
    ok.

code_change(_OldVsn, State, _Extra) ->
    {ok, State}.

handler([Input|Data],L,Cont,M,F,Extra) ->
    case catch apply(M,F,[Cont,Input|Extra]) of
        {done,eof,_} ->
            eof;
        {done,Result,Rest} ->
            {ok,Result,Rest,Data,L+1};
        {more,NCont} ->
            case Data of
                [] -> eof;
                _ -> handler(Data,L+1,NCont,M,F,Extra)
            end
    end.
```